# How to get hittypeid?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

To run `updateHITs.sh`, I have to use the HIT ID and `hittypeid`. I have the ID, but I'm not sure how to get the type from command line tools. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places you can get a HITTypeID using the Command Line Tools. First, it's shown when you create HITs. For example, here's the output run executing run.sh in the helloworld sample:

```
0088653dacfc:helloworld jrb$ ./run.sh 
Unable to find a $JAVA_HOME at "/usr", continuing with system-provided Java...
--[Initializing]----------
 Input: ../samples/helloworld/helloworld.input
 Properties: ../samples/helloworld/helloworld.properties
 Question File: ../samples/helloworld/helloworld.question
 Preview mode disabled
--[Loading HITs]----------
  Start time: Thu Mar 31 17:01:16 PDT 2016
Created HIT 1: HITId=3EHVO81VN5LKU5SFUDTKRPRS0ZQ1HA
Created HIT 2: HITId=3FBEFUUYRK50R4LYUDV95ZV5VFG6A2
Created HIT 3: HITId=307L9TDWJYS8E4S5KF2GK23LKVD3ND
Created HIT 4: HITId=35ZRNT9RUIYQWPSHLU2TZR3QA5I3OS
Created HIT 5: HITId=3X55NP42EOG8HP4I0UF8OR8GKAE3P9

You may see your HIT(s) with HITTypeId '3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0' here: 

  https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0

  End time: Thu Mar 31 17:01:17 PDT 2016
--[Done Loading HITs]----------
  Total load time: 1 seconds.
  Successfully loaded 5 HITs.
```

Also, you can get the HITTypeId in the .success file that's produced when you execute the run.sh command (to create HITs). For example, after I ran the above command, I had a file called helloworld.success in the same folder with the contents of (note I added a few tabs to make it look pretty, but don't try and use this directly in your file, the extra tabs mean it'll probably not work):

```
hitid                           hittypeid
3EHVO81VN5LKU5SFUDTKRPRS0ZQ1HA  3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0
3FBEFUUYRK50R4LYUDV95ZV5VFG6A2  3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0
307L9TDWJYS8E4S5KF2GK23LKVD3ND  3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0
35ZRNT9RUIYQWPSHLU2TZR3QA5I3OS  3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0
3X55NP42EOG8HP4I0UF8OR8GKAE3P9  3PFYYPJUJW5X02IODV4MGVYUBJX2Z0
```

The updateHITs.sh file is expecting a .success file as input. If all you have is a hitid, there's actually a sneaky way to do this. It turns out that you don't actually need a hittypeid in the .success file for it to work. So paste the code into a file, name it something like sneaky.success:

```
hitid
3FBEFUUYRK50R4LYUDV95ZV5VFG6A2
```

And then run the command:

```
./updateHITs.sh -success sneaky.success -properties new_hit.properties
```

Where "new_hit.properties" contains all the properties you want to update these HITs to.

Comment: In conclusion, you can only get this ID if you create the HIT via command line?

Comment: You can get the ID from the API also by calling GetHIT with the HITId. You can get it from the UI by clicking "Manage HITs individually" but if you have a lot of HITs in your account this method may prove unusable. I hope that helps answer your question, but absolutely willing to help add any more color if it'll help. Best of luck!